# How to build an image generation model for interior room design?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, cnn, gan

I want to build an image generator model of interior room design. This model should be able to generate an interior image of a living room/bedroom/hall/kitchen/bathroom. I have searched about it and found out the following websites.

https://interiorai.com/
https://image.computer/

And I made this picture when visiting https://image.computer.
[image: contemporary living room with a large TV and 3 windows]

Above result was perfectly what I want. But free account was restricted to 10 credit images.
And input data don't have to be sentenced, just options are enough for me (e.g. style: modern, type: living, furnitures: [TV: wide, Curtain: white, Window: 3]).

So I decided to google pre-trained model of interior design generator, and finally gave up.

I would like to build a tensorflow (or keras) model that acts just like `image.computer`. Please let me find a model or build a model.

Any support or help would be grateful.

Comment: I have found out corresponding repo recently and managed to test on my laptop.
https://github.com/pixray/pixray.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, I found out the relevant github repository and tested on my laptop.

The repository was https://github.com/pixray/pixray.git

I tested with the following text.
"a white large bedroom with a wide sofa and gray curtain"

And the result was as follows:
[image: Image generation result]